# Untrusted SSL certificate chain. Refusing to communicate with PayPal server - iOS

Tags: ios, ssl, paypal

I'm using `PayPal iOS SDK - 1.4.4`. I haven't updated or done anything to my app. Today I'm getting the message `Untrusted SSL certificate chain. Refusing to communicate with PayPal servers.`

PayPal says it's not on their end, but I haven't done anything with the app. Any ideas? It gets called when I run the following code:

```
[PayPalPaymentViewController setEnvironment:PayPalEnvironmentProduction];
```

Thanks

Comment: I know your question is for iOS, but have you seen this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6659360/how-to-solve-javax-net-ssl-sslhandshakeexception-error

Comment: Also seeing this issue today myself, currently no work around available, on 1.4.6

Comment: Here is a github issue to track the issue we're seeing. https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK/issues/160

Comment: According to the tracking issue, the problem has been solved with a rollback. Voting to close as a problem that cannot be reproduced.

Answer (score 2):

we have identified live issue we will be tracking it here github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK/issues/160 please check there for update.