# Trying to consume Java REST web service which was deployed in WebSphere.I am getting SSLHandshakeException

Tags: java, html, websphere, restful-url

I am Trying to consume Java REST web service which was deployed in WebSphere.
I am getting Error 500: java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure.

How to resolve this Error.

```
function postAjax() {
    var dataTemp=JSON.stringify({userName: "xxxxxx",password: "xxxxxx",feedUrl: "xxxxxx"});
    $.ajax({  
         url:'http://domain-name:9080/Context/service/myService',  
         type:'post', 
         contentType: 'application/json',
         dataType: 'json',
         data: dataTemp,
         success: function(data) { 

         }  
     });  
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to install SSL certificate of the server you are communicating with into java's keystore.

It is already answered here: [How to solve javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException Error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6659360/how-to-solve-javax-net-ssl-sslhandshakeexception-error)