# Unable to Resolve PKIX Path Building Failed

Tags: https, certificate, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

I try to connect to https web service using below code.

adapter.xml:

```
<connectivity>
    <connectionPolicy xsi:type="http:HTTPConnectionPolicyType">
        <protocol>https</protocol>
        <domain>somewhere.com</domain>
        <port>443</port>    
        <connectionTimeoutInMilliseconds>30000</connectionTimeoutInMilliseconds>
        <socketTimeoutInMilliseconds>30000</socketTimeoutInMilliseconds>
        <maxConcurrentConnectionsPerNode>50</maxConcurrentConnectionsPerNode>
    </connectionPolicy>
</connectivity>
```

impl.js:

```
function getTest() {
    var input = {
        method : 'GET',
        returnedContentType : 'json',
        path : "WS.svc"
    };

    return WL.Server.invokeHttp(input);
}
```

Unfortunately, this error appears when I try to call the adapter:

```
{
   "errors": [
      "Runtime: Http request failed: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target"
   ],
   "info": [
   ],
   "isSuccessful": false,
   "warnings": [
   ]
}
```

I have added the public certificate of the WS (accessed from browser and get it from certificate details) into my Java folder in Program Files (`C:\Program Files\Java\jdk_version\jre\lib\security`), however the issue still persists.

Is there any advise?

Comment: inside your java folder in program files? What?

Comment: Hi Idan please see my updated post

Comment: Where did you read this is where you're supposed to put it?

Comment: Here is the reference http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6659360/how-to-solve-javax-net-ssl-sslhandshakeexception-error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The instructions you've followed are incorrect when using MobileFirst Platform.
Follow the steps described in [this user documentation topic](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.installconfig.doc/admin/t_configuring_SSL_WL_adapters_backend_servers_certificates.html) (for Worklight 6.2, but valid for MFPF 6.3 and above as well).

- Do not export the certificate from a browser because this action adds browser metadata and other artifacts which shouldn't be there. Instead use a tool such as OpenSSL to get the certificate (described in the documentation)
- The certificate should then be stored in the keystore of the application server and not in your Java's JVM.

Comment: Yes Idan I agree. I have removed cert from my JVM and added cert to MFP default keystore inside conf folder. But I used the cert extracted from browser. I will let you know the result after imported the cert by using openSSL.

Comment: Idan, it works with both of solution but as you suggest, I import the certificate that extracted by using OpenSSL. Thanks!

Comment: I exported my certificate using the command line in http://serverfault.com/a/129505 and using Firefox, then imported and verified it's in my mfp keystore as mentioned in http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.installconfig.doc/admin/t_configuring_SSL_WL_adapters_backend_servers_certificates.html but I am still having the javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException exception. Anything wrong ?