# Send Post over HTTPS - not working

Tags: java, http, tomcat, http-post

I am trying to send a POST request from my server to my another server. It is working well on http, when executed over https, it says internal server error - Unexpected end of file from the server.  Here is my code for HTTPS POST.

```
URL url = new URL("https://.../Action")
HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
System.out.println("Connection established");
conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", String.valueOf(postDataBytes.length));
conn.setDoOutput(true);
conn.getOutputStream().write(postDataBytes);

//Error in the following line
in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
```

`

Comment: Your another server is configured properly for https ? are you able to hit it from browser using https.

Comment: Yes. I can access both the servers over HTTPS in browser.

Comment: what is the log says at another side. can u post.

Comment: The post request is not reached there :(

Comment: not sure if Content-Type is correct ?

Comment: since it works with HTTP it should be correct i guess. I am actually sending the data as JSON.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117821/discussion-between-anand-and-indra-uprade).

Comment: try setting it as application/json if you are sending json data.

Comment: and one more thing you https call doesn't need any credentials to be authenticated ? i do not see that in your code though

Comment: application/json don't work either. Regarding authentication, I am unsure that should we use any? The only difference I made in my HTTP request and HTTPS is the Http(s)URLConnection and the URL itself.

Comment: Additionally, I also find that if I run 1st server(which will be triggered by browser) over HTTPS and the request (between the two servers ) over HTTP is not working either.

Comment: The detailed error message says SSL handshake exception.:(

Comment: You might want to install other server's cert into your server from where you are trying to invoke the url.

Comment: You are right! I just got it working :) Thank you so much for helping me :)

Comment: not a problem, glad that its working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For HTTPS connection it is important to validate the SSL certificate of another server. For doing this, I used the solution posted by Shirish on the [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6659360/how-to-solve-javax-net-ssl-sslhandshakeexception-error).

Thank you,  @Indra Uprade for helping me to find the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You should use SSLsocket.and you should install the cert into you keystone.