# Android ssl handshake exception map api

Tags: android, ssl, google-maps-api-3

```
   try {
                    String urlImage="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=0,0&zoom=1&size=100x100&key=AIzaSyD_GK1iiZD2kV5J_v6";
                    System.out.println(urlImage);
                    bitmap1 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream) new URL(urlImage).getContent());




                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

when i call this url i get

```
javax.net.ssl.sslhandshakeexception:Handshake failed
```

exception how can i solve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based from this [related SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6742204/5832311), you need to obtain the public certificate from the server you're trying to connect to. *Try contacting the server admin and asking for it, [using openssl to download it](http://www.madboa.com/geek/openssl/#cert-retrieve), or, since this appears to be an HTTP server, connecting to it with any browser, viewing the page's security info, and saving a copy of the certificate.* As stated also in this [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl.html), this can happen for several reasons, including:

- [The CA that issued the server certificate was unknown](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl.html#UnknownCa)
- [The server certificate wasn't signed by a CA, but was self signed](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl.html#SelfSigned)
- [The server configuration is missing an intermediate CA](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl.html#MissingCa)

You can check the documentation which discussed how to address these problems while keeping your connection to the server secure.