# Camel CXF consumer using basic authentication over HTTPS

Tags: ssl, apache-camel, jbossfuse

I am trying to workout how to configure a CXF consumer to use https, but use basic authentication.

I presume we need to attach our certificate using the httpj:engine-factory but whenever I try and do that the server generated the follwing error:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: null cert chain
```

EDIT: I believe what is happening is that the server is requesting a client certificate, but the client does not send one.  For "One Directional" SLL, I don't think the server should be asking for a certificate from the client.

How do I prevent the server from requesting a client certificate?

Any assistance greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be quite simple. In the httpj:engine-factory, there is a setting for client authentication.

```
 <sec:clientAuthentication want="false" required="false"/>
```

This controls whether the server requests a certificate from the client.  I had copied this from samples with Bi-Directional SSL and these values were set to true.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install certificate in your JVM trust store. Please go through below link:
[How to solve javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException Error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6659360/how-to-solve-javax-net-ssl-sslhandshakeexception-error)

Comment: I am not try to connect to a service using one-way SSL.  I am trying to provide a web service that uses one-way SSL.