# Connecting sonarlint with eclipse and sonarqube error

Tags: eclipse, sonarqube, sonarlint

When i'm trying to connect sonarlint with sonarqube I get this error message:

```
"Unable to update data from server 'sonar'
Fail to request https://dev.myserver.com/sonar/api/system/status
```

However when i'm visiting that particular URL it works fine. I'm running SonarLint 2.3.1, SonarQube 5.6.1, java 1.8 and eclipse neon.

SonarLint worked for me without problems prio to the 2.3 update.

Edit: My sonarqube server is only accessible through internal company connection or through VPN. This shouldn't be an issue though as sonarlint has been connected before?

Comment: please post the full stack trace of the error. You can check it either in the SonarLint console or Error Log.

Comment: Because URL is using https, I would bet on a certificate issue. But I don't remember any change in this area between 2.3 and 2.3.1.

Comment: Stacktrace: http://pastebin.com/NYbXz2uk
It seems as there is a certificate issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a certificate issue. Importing the corporate certificate to my cacerts solved my issue as explained here: [How to solve javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException Error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6659360/how-to-solve-javax-net-ssl-sslhandshakeexception-error)