# Getting SSL Handshake exception in FTPS

Tags: java, ssl-certificate, apache-commons-net

```
package routines;


import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPReply;
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPSClient;



import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;

import javax.net.ssl.KeyManager;

import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPFile;
import org.apache.commons.net.util.KeyManagerUtils;

import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocket;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public class FTPSTest {



    public static void main() throws GeneralSecurityException {
        getFile("*******",990,"***","**********","***************","*.csv");
    }


      public static void getFile(String host,
                          int port,
                          String username,
                          String password,
                          String localDirectory,
                          String remoteDirectory,
                          String filemask) throws GeneralSecurityException {
        try {
//          FTPSClient.setTrustManager(null);
          SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2");
          context.init(null, null, new java.security.SecureRandom()); 
          FTPSClient ftpClient = new FTPSClient(true,context);
          // Connect to host
          ftpClient.setTrustManager(null);
          ftpClient.setAuthValue("SSL");
          //ftpClient.setTrustManager(getConfiguration().getCertificatesManager());
          KeyManager keyManager = KeyManagerUtils.createClientKeyManager(new File("/home/global/Desktop/wilson.jks"), "W1nd3n3rgy17!");
          ftpClient.setKeyManager(keyManager);
          ftpClient.connect(host, port);
          int reply = ftpClient.getReplyCode();
          System.out.println(reply);
          if (FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(reply)) {

            // Login
            if (ftpClient.login(username, password)) {

              // Set protection buffer size
              ftpClient.execPBSZ(0);
              // Set data channel protection to private
              ftpClient.execPROT("P");      
              // Enter local passive mode
              ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();

              System.out.println("connected");
```

Code successfully run till this step but when it executes the next line it throws exception

```
              //Get file from host
              for(FTPFile ftpfiles: ftpClient.listDirectories()){
                  System.out.println(">>>"+ftpfiles.getName());
              }
              ftpClient.changeWorkingDirectory(remoteDirectory);
              for(FTPFile ftpfiles: ftpClient.listDirectories()){
                  System.out.println("<<<"+ftpfiles.getName());
              }
              System.out.println("connection established");
              ftpClient.setTrustManager(null);
              FTPFile[] ftpfiles= ftpClient.listFiles(); 
              System.out.println(ftpfiles.length);
              if (ftpfiles != null && ftpfiles.length > 0){
                  for (FTPFile file : ftpfiles) {
                     System.out.println(file.getName());
                     String fileName = file.getName();
                      if (fileName.matches(filemask)){
                        InputStream initialStream=ftpClient.retrieveFileStream(remoteDirectory+File.separatorChar+fileName);
                          byte[] buffer = new byte[initialStream.available()];
                          initialStream.read(buffer);
                         File targetFile = new File(localDirectory+File.separatorChar+fileName);
                         OutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream(targetFile);
                         outStream.write(buffer);
                         outStream.close();

                      }
                  }
              }




          // Logout
          ftpClient.logout();

            } else {
              System.out.println("FTP login failed");
            }

            // Disconnect
            ftpClient.disconnect();

          } else {
            System.out.println("FTP connect to host failed");
          }
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
          System.out.println("FTP client received network error");
        } //catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException nsae) {
         // System.out.println("FTP client could not use SSL algorithm");
        //}
 //catch (GeneralSecurityException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            //e.printStackTrace();
        //}
      }


    private static Object getConfiguration() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
}
```

/***Output*******/

```
   220
connected
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake
  at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:992)
  at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1375)
  at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1403)

FTP client received network error
[statistics] disconnected
  at analytics.etl_load_ftp_0_1.ETL_LOAD_FTP.tJava_4Process(ETL_LOAD_FTP.java:1740)
  at analytics.etl_load_ftp_0_1.ETL_LOAD_FTP.tJava_2Process(ETL_LOAD_FTP.java:1656)
  at analytics.etl_load_ftp_0_1.ETL_LOAD_FTP.tLibraryLoad_1Process(ETL_LOAD_FTP.java:1549)
  at analytics.etl_load_ftp_0_1.ETL_LOAD_FTP.runJobInTOS(ETL_LOAD_FTP.java:2740)
  at analytics.etl_load_ftp_0_1.ETL_LOAD_FTP.main(ETL_LOAD_FTP.java:1849)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: SSL peer shut down incorrectly
  at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:505)
  at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:973)
  ... 17 more
```

It is able to successfully conect but while while fetching files it throws exception Don't know why??

I have also set keymanager suggested by [How to solve javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException Error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6659360/how-to-solve-javax-net-ssl-sslhandshakeexception-error/6742204#6742204)

```
 KeyManager keyManager = KeyManagerUtils.createClientKeyManager(new File("/home/global/Desktop/wilson.jks"), "W1nd3n3rgy17!");
```

I have also set TLSV1.2