# android HttpURLConnection keep getting 302

Tags: android, http

I write an android app, and it works well before, however,recently, I found it is not working. My app parsing json code from the link below:
http://opendata.epa.gov.tw/ws/Data/RainTenMin/?%24format=json

I found that the reason why my app is not working is that the response code is 302,So I google on the internet, and use getHeaderField("Location") in my code
and I found that the redirected url is 
https://opendata.epa.gov.tw/ws/Data/RainTenMin/?%24format=json

So I changed my parsing url to the link with https, however, this time, 
HttpURLConnection throws IOEexception, how can i fix it, thank you for your help.

Below is my code throwing exception:

```
private static String httpRequest(URL rurl) throws IOException{
        String response = "";

        if (rurl == null) {
            return response;
        }
        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        try {
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) rurl.openConnection();
            connection.setConnectTimeout(20000);
            connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            connection.setReadTimeout(25000);
            connection.connect();

            //200 means correctly connected
            int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();

            if (responseCode ==200) {
                inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
                response = readStream(inputStream);
            }
            else {

                MainActivity.connect=false;
                Log.i(logtag, "Error!!  Response code is " + responseCode);
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            MainActivity.connect=false;
            Log.e(logtag, "bad internet!!");}
        finally {
            if (inputStream != null) {
                inputStream.close();
            }
            if (connection != null) {
                connection.disconnect();
            }
        }
        return response;
    }
```

below is the logcat of the error:

```
E/query: bad internet!!
```

Comment: if you changed it with https, then use httpsconnection (https://developer.android.com/reference/javax/net/ssl/HttpsURLConnection.html)

Comment: Please add a logcat of the error

Comment: Don't want to be off-topic, But, why do you don't give a try to [retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) ?

Comment: @Ozn not working, still gets IOEexception

Comment: change GET method with POST

Comment: @OussemaAroua  not working, still gets IOEexception

Comment: Can you share your initial url?

Comment: @BirendraSingh  provided in the question: http://opendata.epa.gov.tw/ws/Data/RainTenMin/?%24format=json

Comment: There is a certificate error on provided url.

Answer (score 0):

What you're getting is a javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException.

You can find some helpful information about how to fix this problem here:
[How to solve javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException Error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6659360/how-to-solve-javax-net-ssl-sslhandshakeexception-error)

Excerpt:

```
TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[]{
                new X509TrustManager() {

                    public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers()
                    {
                        return null;
                    }
                    public void checkClientTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] certs, String authType)
                    {
                        //No need to implement.
                    }
                    public void checkServerTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] certs, String authType)
                    {
                        //No need to implement.
                    }
                }
        };

        // Install the all-trusting trust manager
        try 
        {
            SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
            sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());
            HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());
        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
```