# volley SSLHandshakeException in android 9 Pie

Tags: android, android-volley

I have used volley for request & response data from server. But in android 9 Pie it show error.  My error is bellow..

```
com.android.volley.NoConnectionError: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
```

I have used bellow code for request & response data..

```
private void test() {       
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url_registration,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {

                //response json
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    pDialog.dismiss();
                    e("Err*********>", error.toString());
                }
            }) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
           //paran
            return params;
        }


    };        
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}
```

I have used bellow code in manifest file for android pie

```
 <application    
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" >
</application>
```

Please help me..

Comment: Probably not related to your http client library, refer : https://stackoverflow.com/q/6659360/5208124

I would also like to suggest you to use a more updated http client for Android like Retrofit2.

Comment: @RamithDR I have used volley all my project

Comment: Why dont you add a `SSLCertificateSocketFactory` class? I think it will help

Comment: @MohammadJulfikar Can You help me to implement it..