# Java Spring WS and SSLHandshakeException

Tags: java, web-services, ssl, ssl-certificate, spring-ws

I'm trying to call an Italian webservice, but I'm getting an `SSLHandshakeException` exception. I know this is a security trust problem and I should have a certificate to allow me to communicate using SSL. I would like to know if someone can help me to understand what should be the next steps and how can I generate a valid certificate to communicate with the webservice. Security is not my beach :)

The Italian webservice has a zip folder with a tool for developers and they have there two certificates, but I don't know what I should do with them. YOu can see here: https://sistemats1.sanita.finanze.it/portale/spese-sanitarie/documenti-e-specifiche-tecniche-strumenti-per-lo-sviluppo

Link to the Zip file: (https://sistemats1.sanita.finanze.it/portale/documents/20182/34450/kit730P_ver_20210301.zip/027086e7-385a-6071-ca86-f52077923a85)

You can see my experimental code here: https://github.com/nbentoneves/ws-spring-sts/blob/main/src/main/java/com/github/STSClient.java, feel free to clone and try it.

Note: In the development kit they have a soap project and I was able to call the webservice without needing anything.

STS Test Environment: https://invioSS730pTest.sanita.finanze.it/DocumentoSpesa730pWeb/DocumentoSpesa730pPort

Thanks,

Have a nice code time :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a Trust Manager which does not validate certificate chains like the default ones.

Check this:
([How to solve javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException Error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6659360/how-to-solve-javax-net-ssl-sslhandshakeexception-error))