# rest call is failing from web application where as same code is working from standalone java prog

Tags: java, jboss

rest call is failing from web application where as same code is working from standalone java program.
I have already added the certificate in java cacert.

public static final String SEARCH_API = "https://uat.xxxx.com/rest/obt/external/flight/search";

```
public static void search() throws JSONException {

    DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

    try {

        HttpPost request = new HttpPost(SEARCH_API);
        request.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        request.addHeader("Cookie", "JSESSIONID=54BB4FA63491B14AF7DD6A38BBCE07C5");

        JSONObject dataObject = new JSONObject();

        dataObject.put("isInternational", false);
        dataObject.put("fareClass", "Economy");
        dataObject.put("noOfAdults", 1);
        dataObject.put("noOfChildren", 0);
        dataObject.put("noOfInfant", 0);
        dataObject.put("depDate", "2024-05-24");
        dataObject.put("fromCity", "BLR");
        dataObject.put("toCity", "BOM");
        dataObject.put("tripType", "roundTrip");
        dataObject.put("arrDate", "2024-05-24");
        String requestBody = dataObject.toString();
        System.out.println("SEARCH payload  : " + dataObject.toString());
        StringEntity requestEntity = new StringEntity(requestBody);
        request.setEntity(requestEntity);
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200 && entity != null) {

            String responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
            System.out.println("Search Response : " + responseBody);
        } else {

            System.out.println("Request failed with response code : " + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        ((org.apache.http.client.HttpClient) httpClient).getConnectionManager().shutdown();
    }

}
```

Need help to resolve.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! In what way is it failing exactly? HTTP status other than 200? Runtime error? A different response body to what you're expecting? Please edit this information into your question. Also, are you able to check the web server logs for the API that you're trying to call in case there's a server-side error?

Comment: Getting sslhandshakeexception received fatal alert handshake_failure

Comment: you need to import their certificate to your JKS [check here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6742204/175554)